# Codeigniter Show Individual Custom Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to validate my login form and I have rules on my Username and Password fields.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');
```

So my **callback_check_database** function is on the Password field.

So in my function for check_database, I have:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
return false;
```

So I am setting the custom message that I want to display.

In my view, I want to individually show that check_database error.  I don't want to show any of the other errors.

Here is what I have tried:

```
// does not work
<?php echo form_error('check_database'); ?>

// this works
<?php echo form_error('password'); ?>
```

so since it is for the Password field, it will only show when I echo the password errors.  But that means, since password is a required field, if I don't type anything in it's going to display an error saying that the Password field is required.

Is there a way to only display my custom error message that I set?

Comment: youre doing `callback_check_database` and not `check_database`

Comment: correct.. I need to since I am using a custom validation method that I created. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks

Comment: you are asking on how to handle all errors on form_validation while you set rules on requiring the fields.. simple logic `don't require the fields` pass everything directly to your callback

Comment: well I'm not trying to show all errors, I was seeing if there was a way to only show my check_database error.  I'm guessing this isn't possible though but thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this in two different ways. Both have advantages and disadvantages.

**Option 1:**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'callback_check_database');
```

Then inside the callback_check_database just include a check to make sure $value != "" (which replicates the "required" field).

Note: you should NOT use xss_clean on a password field anyway (since it will alter the password - google it and you'll see examples), and there is zero benefit gained assuming you are hashing the password.

**Option 2:**

Inside your view file, simply type

```
<?php if (form_error('password'))
   {
        echo "Invalid username or password";
   } 
?>
```

This means you are not actually echoing the error, you are simply checking if an error for the password field exists, and regardless what it is, you only show the text above.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the help.  And good looks on the xss_clean on password field, I will definitely take that out.

Comment: note: if your application is already live, and is already using xss_clean - then you are stuck with it, otherwise some people's passwords might stop working